# how to Adding multiple products to cart with single click on add to cart button in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want to add multiple products(different line-items) to cart by single click by add to cart button in Shopify. i tried edit theme and add multiple items to the cart using name="id[]" instead of the standard name="id". but i want to done this work without editing theme.
Please suggest me how do i work? Thank you

Comment: I have built this function in my Shopify store. https://2018hismile.myshopify.com/pages/product-subscriptions Is this the functionality you are after?

Comment: @jordan, sorry i didn't understand what you builded.